# How to Decrypt a key value data stored in mySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I have data in mySQL database table as "2888f3f0-286a-11db-954d-b1740a14150f".
I am not sure how to decrypt it or get the actual text for this value.

Comment: What is that Value supposed to be? And how was it encrypted?

Comment: That looks a lot like a GUID, and not a value. Guessing it's a reference to the data that is somewhere else. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the algorithm/function through which it got encrypted and ultimately you will be able to decrypt the code IF decryption function is available 
otherwise, you can't get the text from this text